# SQL Server procedure - Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHEN'

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

```
USE [DATABASE_NAME]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[upsert_sfdc_account] 
    @sfdc_account_S [dbo].[sfdc_account_type] READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    /* SELECT * FROM [dbo].[sfdc_account] */

    DECLARE @SetColumns VARCHAR(8000) = (SELECT CONCAT(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME),' = S.',QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME),',',CHAR(10))
                                         FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                                         WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'sfdc_account'  
                                         FOR XML PATH(''))

    DECLARE @Columns VARCHAR(4000) = (SELECT QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + ','
                                      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                                      WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'sfdc_account' 
                                      FOR XML PATH(''))

  SET @SetColumns = SUBSTRING(@SetColumns, 53, LEN(@SetColumns) - 54)
  SET @Columns = SUBSTRING(@Columns, 6, LEN(@Columns) - 6)

  SELECT @SetColumns
  SELECT @Columns

  MERGE [dbo].[sfdc_account] AS T
  USING @sfdc_account_S AS S
  ON (T.Salesforce_Id = S.Salesforce_Id)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET @SetColumns
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT(@Columns)
    VALUES(@Columns)
END
```

I get this error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure upsert_sfdc_account, Line 40
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHEN'.

I cannot seem to get this to execute properly. What am I missing?

The substring produces these values:

> @SetColumns
>
> [IsDeleted] = S.[IsDeleted], [MasterRecordId] = S.[MasterRecordId],
>   [Name] = S.[Name], [Type] = S.[Type], [RecordTypeId] =
>   S.[RecordTypeId], [ParentId] = S.[ParentId], [BillingStreet] =
>   S.[BillingStreet], [BillingCity] = S.[BillingCity], [BillingState] =
>   S.[BillingState], [BillingPostalCode] = S.[BillingPostalCode],
>   [BillingCountry] = S.[BillingCountry], [BillingStateCode] =
>   S.[BillingStateCode], [BillingCountryCode] = S.[BillingCountryCode],
>   [BillingLatitude] = S.[BillingLatitude], [BillingLongitude] =
>   S.[BillingLongitude], [BillingGeocodeAccuracy] =
>   S.[BillingGeocodeAccuracy], [ShippingStreet] = S.[ShippingStreet],
>   [ShippingCity] = S.[ShippingCity], [ShippingState] =
>   S.[ShippingState], [ShippingPostalCode] = S.[ShippingPostalCode],
>   [ShippingCountry] = S.[ShippingCountry], [ShippingStateCode] =
>   S.[ShippingStateCode], [ShippingCountryCode] =
>   S.[ShippingCountryCode], [ShippingLatitude] = S.[ShippingLatitude],
>   [ShippingLongitude] = S.[ShippingLongitude], [ShippingGeocodeAccuracy]
>   = S.[ShippingGeocodeAccuracy], [Phone] = S.[Phone], [Fax] = S.[Fax], [AccountNumber] = S.[AccountNumber], [Website] = S.[Website],
>   [PhotoUrl] = S.[PhotoUrl], [Sic] = S.[Sic], [Industry] = S.[Industry],
>   [AnnualRevenue] = S.[AnnualRevenue], [NumberOfEmployees] =
>   S.[NumberOfEmployees], [Ownership] = S.[Ownership], [TickerSymbol] =
>   S.[TickerSymbol], [Description] = S.[Description], [Rating] =
>   S.[Rating], [Site] = S.[Site], [CurrencyIsoCode] =
>   S.[CurrencyIsoCode], [OwnerId] = S.[OwnerId], [CreatedDate] =
>   S.[CreatedDate], [CreatedById] = S.[CreatedById], [LastModifiedDate] =
>   S.[LastModifiedDate], [LastModifiedById] = S.[LastModifiedById],
>   [SystemModstamp] = S.[SystemModstamp], [LastActivityDate] =
>   S.[LastActivityDate], [LastViewedDate] = S.[LastViewedDate],
>   [Sales_Ready__c] = S.[Sales_Ready__c]
>
> @Columns
>
> [Salesforce_Id],[IsDeleted],[MasterRecordId],[Name],[Type],[RecordTypeId],[ParentId],[BillingStreet],[BillingCity],[BillingState],[BillingPostalCode],[BillingCountry],[BillingStateCode],[BillingCountryCode],[BillingLatitude],[BillingLongitude],[BillingGeocodeAccuracy],[ShippingStreet],[ShippingCity],[ShippingState],[ShippingPostalCode],[ShippingCountry],[ShippingStateCode],[ShippingCountryCode],[ShippingLatitude],[ShippingLongitude],[ShippingGeocodeAccuracy],[Phone],[Fax],[AccountNumber],[Website],[PhotoUrl],[Sic],[Industry],[AnnualRevenue],[NumberOfEmployees],[Ownership],[TickerSymbol],[Description],[Rating],[Site],[CurrencyIsoCode],[OwnerId],[CreatedDate],[CreatedById],[LastModifiedDate],[LastModifiedById],[SystemModstamp],[LastActivityDate],[LastViewedDate],[Sales_Ready__c]

Answer (score 1):

You need a semicolon to end the merge.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql

> The MERGE statement requires a semicolon (;) as a statement terminator.

Comment: Actually, the statement before the `MERGE` statement must be terminated with a semi-colon (`SELECT @Columns;`). Alternatively, the semi-colon may be added before the `MERGE` thanks to lax T-SQL statement parsing (http://www.dbdelta.com/always-use-semicolon-statement-terminators/).